# Django admin make changes to selected user?

Tags: python, django

So I have created a inline class in my admin.py and some actions to update a selected user. The problem I am facing is that when I select a user and perform said action it only ever updates the admin user....which I am guessing is because I am using `request`. I am trying to get the action to update the selected user(s) and not the admin user initiating the action, but I have been struggling with it for a couple days now off and on trying to figure this out. When using `queryset` I get error messages saying `'Queryset' object has no attribute 'profile'` but I am not sure what else to use here. So mu question is, is what I am trying to do possible and if so any guidance on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated. Please see my code below.

admin.py

```
admin.site.unregister(User)


class ProfileAdminInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile


class ProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                    'rewards_punch_card', 'rewards_tier']
    list_select_related = True
    inlines = [ProfileAdminInLine]

    actions = ['pc_add_1', 'pc_add_2', 'pc_add_3', 'pc_add_4', 'pc_add_5',
               'pc_add_6', 'pc_add_7', 'pc_add_8', 'pc_add_9']

    def rewards_tier(self, user):
        return user.profile.rewards_tier

    def rewards_punch_card(self, user):
        return user.profile.rewards_current

    def pc_add_1(self, request, queryset):

        punch_card = request.user.profile.rewards_current
        tier = request.user.profile.rewards_tier
        credits = request.user.profile.rewards_credits

        user_profile = request.user.profile

        punch_cards_updated = punch_card + 1

        if punch_cards_updated == 10:
            request.user.profile.rewards_current = 0
            user_profile.save()
            if tier == 1:
                request.user.profile.rewards_tier = tier + 1
                request.user.profile.rewards_credits = credits + 25
                user_profile.save()
            elif tier == 2:
                request.user.profile.rewards_tier = tier + 1
                request.user.profile.rewards_credits = credits + 30
                user_profile.save()
            elif tier == 3:
                request.user.profile.rewards_tier = tier + 1
                request.user.profile.rewards_credits = credits + 35
                user_profile.save()
            elif tier == 4:
                request.user.profile.rewards_tier = tier + 1
                request.user.profile.rewards_credits = credits + 40
                user_profile.save()
            elif tier == 5:
                request.user.profile.rewards_credits = credits + 50
                user_profile.save()
            elif tier == 6:
                request.user.profile.rewards_credits = credits + 50
                user_profile.save()

        else:
            request.user.profile.rewards_current = punch_card + 1
            user_profile.save()

        self.message_user(request, "Users were successfully updated by 1 item.")
```

Comment: `queryset` contains the list of profiles that are selected in the admin: you should use that directly. However it's not clear what you actually want to do with the profiles; your code doesn't change anything.

Comment: As shown in this line `punch_cards_updated = punch_card + 1` I am trying to add one to the `user.profile.rewards_current` object. When using `queryset` I am getting an attribute error stating the Queryset contains no attribute profile. I update my code to show the whole picture of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: But do you want to save the result? Even if this code worked, it still wouldn't do anything without saving.

Comment: I updated the code to show the whole picture as to what I am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, `queryset` is the set of selected user profiles. So you just need to iterate over that. Obviously, you also need to consistently use the profile from the loop, rather than from request.user.

```
def pc_add_1(self, request, queryset):

    for user_profile in queryset:

        punch_card = user_profile.rewards_current
        tier = user_profile.rewards_tier
        credits = user_profile.rewards_credits

        punch_cards_updated = punch_card + 1

        if punch_cards_updated == 10:
            user_profile.rewards_current = 0
            if tier == 1:
                user_profile.rewards_tier = tier + 1
                user_profile.rewards_credits = credits + 25
        ...
        user_profile.save()
```

(One minor point: you don't seem to be doing anything with `punch_cards_updated`; did you mean to set that back to `user_profile.rewards_current`?)

Comment: That worked, thank you! As far as `punch_cards_updated` I am using that to check what the punch card is at in terms of value. As I have functions going to `pc_add_9` when the value is `18` for example I reset the punchcard to 8. The reason for this is if the punchcard is ever at 10 or above I want it to just roll over.